# What is the best way to globally catch ajax errors in asp.net-mvc?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I find myself putting this (simplified) code in a number of different javascript files:

```
 $(document).ajaxError(function (e, xhr, settings, exception) {
     alert('error in: ' + 
                         settings.url + ' \\n' + 
                         'error:\\n' + exception + 
                         ": " + xhr.responseText
          );
 });
```

is there any downside that someone can think of by just putting this in my Site.Master file once so I have a consistent solution to errors?.  If I do that, is there anyway to override the behavior on a specific page?

Comment: showing the url or the exception to the end user does not make any sense... just show the error message from the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(document).ajaxError` in your `Site.Master` file.

To override this in a specific instance, then just include the `error` callback on individual AJAX calls, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/yourUrl',
    success: function(result) {
        alert('It worked!');
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Your custom error message here.');
    }
});
```

For those that you do not want to override, them omit the `error` callback.

Comment: out of curiosity, What is the difference between the ajaxSetup() versus just having the  $(document).ajaxError call directly as I have in the above question?

Comment: Wow, just read the documentation for this and it appears that using jQuery `.ajaxSetup({error:{);` is considered a bad practice and it is encouraged to use the `$(document).ajaxError` handler instead, I am updating my answer to reflect that.